# Get error Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new in swift, I'm trying create an Alarm, but get an error.
Can I use NSUserDefaults like in the code below, and how can I fix this error?

The error I get is:

```
Could not cast value of type 'NSTaggedPointerString'  to 'NSArray'
```

and occurs in this line:

```
let alarms = defaults.objectForKey("Alarms") as! [String]
```

My whole class:

```
class Alarm {

    // MARK: - Declare 2 fields just time and switch in alarm

    var time: String = ""
    var stateSwitch: Bool = false

    // MARK: - Initalize
    init(time: String , turnOn: Bool) {
        self.time = time
        self.stateSwitch = turnOn
    }


    class func getAllAlarm() -> [Alarm] {

        var alarms = [Alarm]()
        let times = getAllTimes()
        let stateSwitchs = getAllSwitchs()

        for i in 0...times.count {

            let alarm = Alarm(time: times[i], turnOn: stateSwitchs[i])

            alarms.append(alarm)

        }

        return alarms
    }

    private class func getAllTimes() -> [String]{

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        let alarms = defaults.objectForKey("Alarms") as! [String]
        return alarms
    }

    private class func getAllSwitchs() -> [Bool]{
        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        let stateSwitchs = defaults.objectForKey("Switchs") as! [Bool]
        return stateSwitchs
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems that you previously saved a String object into NSUserDefaults at "Alarms" key so you can't transform it as a [String].

Answer (score 0):

You use `NSUserdefaults` correctly for getting an object. The problem is probably where you set the data.

```
as! [String]
```

in function `getAllTimes` does a force cast, it casts whatever object you get to a `String` array. If that object cannot be casted (because you inserted a different type), this will fail.

So meaning, if you saved a String array to `NSUserdefaults`, this would succeed.

To be sure you should show the code where you save to NSUserDefaults.